# dictionary from a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-mining

I do have a file `f1` which has words and an emotional values (values from +6 to -6)

```
normal  0
sad -2
happy   4
```

I have another file `f2` which has texts (tweets) containing say average of 4 or 5 words (line by line).

I want to read text in `f2` line by line and for each line, for every word I have to search whether it is there in `f1`. If it is, then I have to get the value and add it. Likewise I have to sum values for every word (if it is in the list) in the sentence and print it.
So print should be like this (for example for first three lines)

```
3
0
-2
```

I have a code like this.I am getting error "value error:mixing iterating and read method will loose data" Please correct the code or at least give a new method to do this.

```
f2=open("file2.txt","r")
for line in f2:
    l=f2.readline()
    afinn = dict(map(lambda (k,v): (k,int(v)),[ line.split('\t') for line in open("file1.txt") ]))
    value= sum(map(lambda word: afinn.get(word, 0), l.lower().split()))
    print value
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow! I think you really should read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to learn the basic editor features here. I'll try and fix your post for you this time.

Comment: What does *"This isn't working"* mean? Do you get errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: Please don't use `map(lambda...` ever - in every single case where you are doing this you should use a list/dict comprehension or simply a generator expression instead!

Comment: thanks sir i'll learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

```
for line in f2:
    l=f2.readline()
```

You're iterating over the file implicitly *and* explicitly at the same time - not a good idea. In the first iteration `line` will contain the first line of your file, and `l` will contain the second line. In the next iteration, `line` and `l` will contain the third and fourth line, respectively (and so on). Pick one - I would choose the first one and drop the `readline()` call.

Then, you *reassign*  line in your list comprehension that's reading `file1.txt`. That means you're overwriting `line`, and you're reading `file1.txt` again and again during each iteration - a huge waste. Read it once, store it and refer to that in your loop.

Furthermore, `dict(map(lambda(...)))` is rather unpythonic - we do have dict comprehensions for that. But in this case, a simpler version is probably even better:

This is how you could fill your `words` dictionary (you could do that as a one-liner too, but readability counts, so let's keep it simple):

```
with open("file1.txt") as f1:
    words = {}
    for line in f1:
        word, score = line.split()
        words[word] = int(score)
```

Now you could go and read your input file:

```
with open("file2.txt") as f2:
    for line in f2:
        contents = line.split()
        value = sum(words.get(word, 0) for word in contents)
        print value
```

Comment: k thank you sir and i'll correct it. I will try to use dict for the same. If any other method pls tell.

Comment: sir i am getting an error while adding ele to dictionary."value error:too many errors to unpack". what shall i do?

Comment: That means that there are more than two whitespace-separated elements on at least one of the lines in `file1.txt`. Add a `print line` at the start of the `for` loop so you can see which line it fails on.

Comment: ya first part works sir and in second part i get error "type error" unsupported operand type for +:'int' and 'none type'

Comment: @SelvaPerumal: Can you check if your code uses the `.get(word, 0)` version instead of just `.get(word)`? Otherwise, I'm not sure how you'd get that error.

Comment: great sir it works wonderful. I am really obliged to you.Finally, how can i become good python programmer like you?

Comment: @SelvaPerumal: Thanks, no problem. I started by reading the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html) and also O'Reilly's "Learning Python".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using my word list AFINN from http://www2.compute.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/6010/zip/imm6010.zip

Note that there is a tab character between the 'word' and the value and that some of the 'words' are not single words but phrases such as 'not good'. You should be using another split character. Copying and modifying Tim Pitzcker's code:

`with open("AFINN-111.txt") as f1:
    words = {}
    for line in f1:
        word, score = line.split('\t')
        words[word] = float(score)`

Yours and Tim Pitzcker's code may also have a problem with the tokenization of the second file, e.g., the below code really doesn't work because split is splitting by default on the whitespace, ignoring the comma:

`line = 'It what bad, plain and simply bad.'
contents = line.split()
value = sum(words.get(word, 0) for word in contents)`

You probably need to look into re.split() or nltk.word_tokenize as well as lowercase the words.

Comment: ya thanks for ur answer Finn. I customized the code according to my requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Also note that you need UTF-8 encoding for the word naïve in the word list.